# A proof of the definition of Haar functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

Let $I = I_{j,k}$ be a dyadic interval. The Haar function associated with I is defined by$$h_{j,k}(x) =\frac{1}{|I|} (\chi_{I_{R}(x)} - \chi_{I_{L}(x)} ),$$ where, $I_{R} = [(2k + 1)2^{-j-1}, (k+1)2^{-j}[$, $I_{L} = [k2^{-j}, (2k+1)2^{-j-1}[.$

Also I want to Show that $$h_{j,k}(x) = 2^{j/2} h_{0,0}(2^{j}x - k).$$

But I feel that this formula contains something wrong in $2^{j/2}$, because I tried the definition given in the question statement for the Haar function (that includes $\chi$)for $j=k=1$, then I tried the definition for the Haar function that we require to prove (that contains $h_{0,0}$) for $j=k=1$, but 1/(the length of the interval was different), (1/the length of the interval as I calculated was 4 but the new formula gives $\sqrt{2}$ )? do you see my problem? did anyone agree with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$h_{0,0}(x)=\begin{cases}-1 & 0≤x<\frac12\\
1& \frac12≤x<1\end{cases}\qquad |I|\cdot h_{i,j}(x)=\begin{cases}-1 & k≤2^jx<k+\frac12\\
1& k+\frac12≤2^jx<k+1\end{cases}$$
where I would usually say $|I|=2^{-j}$, but your result needs $|I|=2^{-j/2}$. At any rate compare the two expressions by using the explicit form of $h$ that I wrote out before.

Comment: I did not understand what you said, could you clarify please?

Comment: I had forgotten to write the arguments of the functions, oops. What I mean is: explicitly write out what $h_{i,j}(x)$ is to see that the equality you desire holds.

Comment: I tried the definition given in the question statement  for the Haar function (that includes $\chi$)for j=k=1, then I tried the definition for the Haar function that we require to prove (that contains $h_{0,0}$) for j=k=1, but 1/(the length of the interval was diiferent) (1/the length of the interval as I calculated was 4 but the new formula gives $\sqrt 2$ )? do you see my problem?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. The formula you have ($h_{j,k}(x) = 2^{j/2} h_{0,0}(2^jx-k)$) can only be true if $|I|=2^{-j/2}$. I would usually say $|I|=2^{-j}$. If you take that, then the formula must be $h_{j,k}(x) = 2^{j} h_{0,0}(2^jx-k)$.